# Push Plugin notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-pushplugin

Why can't I receive push notification when my app is already running or opened? I'm using push plugin.
Here is my code:

```
<script>
    var tokenID = "";
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
        //Unregister the previous token because it might have become invalid. Unregister everytime app is started.
//            window.plugins.pushNotification.unregister(successHandler, errorHandler);
        if(intel.xdk.device.platform == "Android")
        {
            //register the user and get token
            window.plugins.pushNotification.register(
            successHandler,
            errorHandler,
            {
                //project ID from Google Cloud Messaging
                "senderID":"749289157135",
                //callback function that is executed when phone recieves a notification for this app
                "ecb":"onNotification"
            });
        } 
    }, false);
    //app given permission to receive and display push messages in Android.
    function successHandler (result) {
        // alert('result = ' + result);
    }

    //app denied permission to receive and display push messages in Android.
    function errorHandler (error) {
        alert('error = ' + error);
    }
    //fired when token is generated, message is received or an error occured.
    function onNotification(e) 
    {
        switch( e.event )
        {
            //app is registered to receive notification
            case 'registered':
                if(e.regid.length > 0)
                {
                    // Your Android push server needs to know the token before it can push to this device
        // here is where you might want to send the token to your server along with user credentials.
                    // if(localStorage.getItem('deviceID') != "" || localStorage.getItem("deviceID") != NULL || localStorage.getItem("puID") !="" || localStorage.getItem("puID") != NULL){
                    //     window.location = "emergencyCode.html";
                    // }
                    // else{
                        tokenID = e.regid;
                        localStorage.setItem("deviceID", tokenID);
                        window.location = "start.html"; 

                }
            break;
            case 'message':
                if ( e.foreground ) {
                   alert("foreground");
                } else {
                    if ( e.coldstart )  {
                        // window.location = "login.html";
                        alert('name = ' + e.payload.name);
                        alert('lat = ' + e.payload.lat);
                        alert('lng = ' + e.payload.lng);

                    } else {
                        alert("BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION");
                    }
                }
            break;
            case 'error':
              alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
            break;
            default:
              alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
            break;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) receives notification if your application is closed or open. If your application is closed, the plugin *creates a notification* in the **notification area**. But if your application is open, it will pass the notification data to your application *without creating a notification*.

So you will always get the notification data sent from your server in the configured `ecb` but it will not always create a notification

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons for push notification not working. Make sure your registration ID, tokens, server, etc are valid and working. Make sure all your requirements are met first by reading the following [**doc**](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html). Hope this gives you a starting point to catch your error.

Comment: my push notification is ok can receive when the app is exit. .when my app is open or already running the notification can't receive how to solve this. .